# How to get Username before Authenticating User in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, active-directory, basic-authentication, spring-security-ldap

How to get username before redirecting the page to login for authenticating user using HTTP Basic Authentication with Active Directory in Spring Boot.

My Security Class as shown below:

```
@Configuration
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

            ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
                    this.ldapDomain, this.ldapUrl);

            adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
            adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);

            // Checks with the Distinguished Name pattern provided
            if (this.ldapUserDnPattern != null && this.ldapUserDnPattern.trim().length() > 0) {
                adProvider.setSearchFilter(this.ldapUserDnPattern);
            }

            auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);

        }

    }
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: You could create a custom filter and add it before BasicAuthenticationFilter. Instructions here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter

Comment: Can you please check my post now and help me on this. Thanks @ Mukul Goel